# Overloading in Typescript for Simple Add function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've tried to test this sample but when I passed two parameter it gave me 'NaN'

```js
class TestClass {


    add(a: number, b: number): number;
    add(a: number, b: number, c: number): number;
    add(a: number, b: number, c?: number): number {
        if (a && b && c) {
            return a + b + c;
        }
        else {
            return a + b ;
        }
    }

}

let objv = new TestClass();
console.log(objv.add(15, 10));   // NAN
console.log(objv.add(15, 10 , 20)); // It works
```

Comment: Seems to work for me

Comment: Are you sure ? I just tested, I got 25 on the first one. Which version of ts are you using?

Comment: Same, working for me

Comment: Thanks , It's worked now